# Why doesn't gunicorn reply to CloudFoundry health checks when running a cherrypy app behind NGINX?

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, cloud-foundry, cherrypy, http-status-code-302

- I am deploying a `cherrypy` application on CloudFoundry.
- I have set `health-check-type: http` in my app manifest.
- I have `NGINX` setup as a reverse proxy (see config below).
- I used to start the cherrypy web server like this: `python3 -u app.py` and that has been working alright, but apparently that isn't recommended for various reasons.
- I am now trying to run `gunicorn` around the cherrypy code like this: `gunicorn -w 1 -t 300 -b :8080 app:app` - this is when I couldn't get the app to turn healthy on startup any longer.

In CloudFoundry you can choose between different [health checks](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/healthchecks.html) with the default being `port`. Setting the `health-check-type` to `port` actually allows `gunicorn` to start up and properly serve requests. However, when I set `health-check-type: http` the start-up fails.

I can see this in the logs:

```
   2018-11-28T21:10:39.12+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2018-11-28T21:10:39.30+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Start nginx ...
   2018-11-28T21:10:39.34+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Starting nginx: nginx.
   2018-11-28T21:10:39.34+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Start app ...
   2018-11-28T21:10:39.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [2018-11-28 20:10:39 +0000] [94] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
   2018-11-28T21:10:39.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [2018-11-28 20:10:39 +0000] [94] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (94)
   2018-11-28T21:10:39.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [2018-11-28 20:10:39 +0000] [94] [INFO] Using worker: sync
   2018-11-28T21:10:39.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [2018-11-28 20:10:39 +0000] [134] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 134
   2018-11-28T21:10:43.67+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [28/Nov/2018:20:10:43] ENGINE Bus STARTING
   2018-11-28T21:10:43.67+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [28/Nov/2018:20:10:43] ENGINE Starting up DB access
   2018-11-28T21:10:43.67+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [28/Nov/2018:20:10:43] ENGINE Bus STARTED
```

which looks to me as if everything is going alright up to this point. However, after some start-up tasks have completed, the health monitoring produces the outputs below over and over again until the start-up finally times out:

```
   2018-11-28T21:11:17.97+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2018:20:11:17] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 100 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"
   2018-11-28T21:11:17.98+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [28/Nov/2018:20:11:17]  [METRICS] [/] took 0.0024
   2018-11-28T21:11:17.98+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2018:20:11:17] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 100 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"
   2018-11-28T21:11:17.99+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [28/Nov/2018:20:11:17]  [METRICS] [/] took 0.0030
   2018-11-28T21:11:17.99+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2018:20:11:17] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 100 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"
   2018-11-28T21:11:18.00+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [28/Nov/2018:20:11:18]  [METRICS] [/] took 0.0028
   2018-11-28T21:11:18.00+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2018:20:11:18] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 100 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"
   2018-11-28T21:11:18.01+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [28/Nov/2018:20:11:18]  [METRICS] [/] took 0.0028
   2018-11-28T21:11:18.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2018:20:11:18] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 100 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"
   2018-11-28T21:11:18.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [28/Nov/2018:20:11:18]  [METRICS] [/] took 0.0027
   2018-11-28T21:11:18.03+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2018:20:11:18] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 100 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"
   2018-11-28T21:11:18.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [28/Nov/2018:20:11:18]  [METRICS] [/] took 0.0027
```

It looks like `gunicorn` or `NGINX` replies with status code: `302` instead of a `200`, which is what the health check is expecting.

If I change the `health-check-type` back to `port` everything is working again and the app starts up and magically works. Unfortunately, I really want to use the other `health-check-type: http` (to be able to use the `health-check-http-endpoint`).

**Any idea what I might be missing in my setup here?**

- I have tried running `gunicorn` locally, which works fine.
- I am also deploying 4 other applications with `gunicorn` in a very similar configuration (including `NGINX` and `cherrypy` or `flask`) and at least one of those has the `health-check-type: http` option working without the described issues.

*NGINX reverse proxy config for reference:*

```
server {

    # Running port
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    # Form submission size
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location / {

        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_connect_timeout       300;
        proxy_send_timeout          300;
        proxy_read_timeout          300;
        send_timeout                300;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is a location of 302 redirect for healthcheck "GET /" request?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the problem here. `cherrypy` handles a "trailing slash" in the URL differently when running on it's own or when running under `gunicorn`.

There are related `cherrypy` bug reports here:
https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/1624
https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/1185

What happened when my health check was requesting: `/health` was that `gunicorn` issued a `302 permanent redirect` to `/health/` which meant the health check failed (as it didn't return `200`).

Changing the health check URL to `/health/` worked in this situation.